# NodeJS Request - login into website

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, web-crawler

i'm very new to Javascript and i just want to login into website from NodeJS request. This website need information from the first time visited to login.

Here is my code.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var loginLink = 'link';
var loginJar = request.jar();
var ltValue = '';

request.get({url: loginLink, jar: loginJar}, function(err, httpResponse, html)
{
   var dat = cheerio.load(html);
   var arr = dat('input[name="lt"]');
   ltValue = arr.attr('value');
   arr = dat('input[name="execution"]');
   executionValue = arr.attr('value');
   /*Post body*/
   var loginBody = 'username=' + usn + '&password=' + pwd + '&lt=' + ltValue + '&execution=' + executionValue
   request.post({url: loginLink, jar: loginJar, method: 'post', json: true, body: loginBody, }}, function(err, res, b)
   {
     if (b.indexOf('errors')  != -1)
        console.log("Success");
     else console.log("Fail");
   });
 });
```

I have write try it in C# and it work correctly but in my NodeJs code it always return fail. I have tried everytime but i couldn't do it. Please help me with this problem.

```
    byte[] binData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginBody)
    string loginFile = "loginInfo.txt";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("link");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = binData.Length;
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(binData, 0, binData.Length);
    }
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(loginFile, reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    string loginData = userID + " " + password;
    File.WriteAllText("login.txt", loginData);
```

Comment: check error using console.log(b.errors) or console.log(JSON.stringify(b))

Comment: I did. This code just turn into the login error page